# How can I validate my implementation of Ansi 9.19?

Tags: mac

I implemented an Ansi 9.19 mac generator in java, but now I don't know how to validate its functionality. I couldn't find any sample of a {plain text,key,mac} on the internet, and I want to know if there is a good way to test my implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bouncy Castle has an [ISO 9797/ANSI 9.19 Mac implementation](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/macs/ISO9797Alg3Mac.java) with a [test vector](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/test/ISO9797Alg3MacTest.java).

Botan also has an implementation and [test vectors](https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/net.randombit.botan/src/tests/data/mac/x919_mac.vec), which cross-verify with Bouncy Castle (at least the 128 bit key ones anyway).

From the looks, official test vectors appear to be scarce (unless you want to pay for a copy of the standard and chance one being in there), and it's less than clear that the BC/Botan vectors are official, so cross testing with existing implementations might be the best you can manage.